# How can I use join for returned result?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Now I have the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_city(_city_id bigint, _country_id integer, _lat float, lon float) RETURNS geo_cities LANGUAGE plpgsql as $$
    DECLARE
            city_coords Geometry := ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(_lon, _lat), 3395);
            result record;
    BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM geo_cities gc WHERE gc.id = _city_id)
            THEN
                    UPDATE geo_cities
                    SET coords = city_coords, country_id = _country_id
                    WHERE id = _city_id
                    RETURNING * INTO result;
            ELSE
                    INSERT INTO geo_cities(id, country_id, coords)
                    VALUES (_city_id, _country_id, city_coords)
                    RETURNING * INTO result;
            END IF;
            RETURN result;
    END;
 $$
```

I want to use join with my result. That's what I mean:

```
  ...
  RETURNING 
    id as city_id,
    ST_X(coords) as lon,
  INNER JOIN geo_countries as gc ON gc.id = id
  ...
```

Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the result of a function call to a table, but in a slightly different way:

```
SELECT
    gc.col_1, gc.col_2, /* ... as many as needed */
    city.id AS city_id, ST_X(city.coords) AS lon
FROM
    set_city(1234, 5678, 1.23, 3.45) AS city
    JOIN geo_countries AS gc ON gc.id = city.id
```

So, in practice, `set_city(...)` behaves in the `SELECT` just is if it were any other kind of table.

Comment: Why do you need to create a second function? What for?

Comment: This need for me, because I don't want to use queries directly. For that I created this question, because I don't understand how I can do this with one function. Now I have the second function, but I think it is not so good... In any case thanks for your advice

Comment: Sorry, I *don't understand your question*.  "How can I **USE JOIN** for returned result?" I think you need to explain better, give an example, ...

Comment: Аfter insert a new row I want to retrieve the newly created row, but with additional joins. I mean something like this: `INSERT INTO geo_cities(id, country_id, coords) VALUES (_city_id, _country_id, city_coords) RETURNING * INTO result; RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM result INNER JOIN ...;`
` I want to do this inside one function. Is this possible?